# Apache PDFBox: Is there a way to use only streams?

Tags: java, pdfbox

My code needs to pull an image from an S3 InputStream, create a PDF, add it to a ZipOutputStream, and finally use an OutputStream to send it back to the user. I'd really like to accomplish this without reading any bytes into memory. Currently I'm doing all of the above (minus the PDF conversion) with this code:

```
    public void myFunction(List<String> fileKeys, OutputStream responseStream) throws Exception {
        ZipOutputStream zipOutput = new ZipOutputStream(responseStream);

        for (String fileKey : fileKeys) {
            S3Object s3Obj = getS3Object(fileKey);
            try (InputStream data = s3Obj.getObjectContent()) {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileKey);
                zipOutput.putNextEntry(entry);
                IOUtils.copy(data, zipOutput);
                zipOutput.closeEntry();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        zipOutput.close();
    }
```

I can't however for the life of me figure out how to get PDFBox to not read bytes of the images into memory. Maybe this isn't possible? I have some working code now, but monitoring the JVM Heap shows alot of stuff going into memory.

```
    public void myFunction(List<String> fileKeys, OutputStream responseStream) throws Exception {
        ZipOutputStream zipOutput = new ZipOutputStream(responseStream);

        for (String fileKey : fileKeys) {
            S3Object s3Obj = getS3Object(fileKey);
            try (InputStream data = s3Obj.getObjectContent()) {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileKey);
                zipOutput.putNextEntry(entry);

                BufferedImage bim = ImageIO.read(data);
                PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
                PDPage page = new PDPage();
                doc.addPage(page);
                PDImageXObject pdImage = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(doc, bim);
                PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
                contents.drawImage(pdImage, 50, 50);

                contents.beginText();
                contents.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 8);
                contents.showText("Document: " + fileKey);
                contents.endText();

                contents.close();
                COSWriter writer = new COSWriter(zipOutput);
                writer.write(doc);
                doc.close();

                zipOutput.closeEntry();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        zipOutput.close();
    }
```

Comment: PDFBox always reads the image into memory to get the size. Btw if that image is originally in JPEG then you should use the other method from that factory, that would be faster and avoids reencoding.

Comment: There is a weakness in the current code that the image is decoded although only its metadata is needed. I have created an issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4691  However solving this will only have a medium improvement.

Comment: You can get a snapshot build here in a few hours: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.18-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr, appreciate the quick turnaround. Could you give me an example of how I can take advantage of your change? Also, is it possible to get similar behavior from the LosslessFactory as well? I didn't include it in my example, but we're using that for other file types.

Comment: You could use `PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray()`. You still need to load the file into a byte array but this has been done before. However it will also take advantage on new code that processes PNG files directly (when possible, for some content types it will fall back into decoding). This is very recent so you'll find it only in the snapshot version.